# Palindrome doesn't work inside of a function

Tags: python, function, palindrome

I got error of below code while placed in def : " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'czy_to_palindrome' referenced before assignment"
It works fine without.

DOES NOT WORK:

```
while True:
    print("Podaj liczbe: ", end="")
    number = input()
    czy_to_palindrome = True
    def palindrome_check(number):
        for i in range(len(number)):
            if number[i] != number[len(number)- i - 1]:
                print("No, ", number, "is NOT a palindrome.")
                czy_to_palindrome = False
                break
        if czy_to_palindrome:
           print("Yes, ",number, "is a palindrome.")

    palindrome_check(number)
```

WORKS:

```
while True:
    print("Podaj liczbe: ", end="")
    number = input()
    czy_to_palindrome = True
    # def palindrome_check(number):
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if number[i] != number[len(number)- i - 1]:
            print("No, ", number, "is NOT a palindrome.")
            czy_to_palindrome = False
            break
    if czy_to_palindrome:
        print("Yes, ",number, "is a palindrome.")

    # palindrome_check(number)
```

Explain please what function change I do not understand. Thanks
Begginer in codeing.

Comment: Look up "scope of variables" in python.

Comment: Well, it looks like you want us to resolve your homework, kid. Look up global reserved work in python

Comment: there is only one error on you inner function that `czy_to_palindrome` not defined in it try this it will access global `czy_to_palindrome` inside your `palindrome_check` function "`global czy_to_palindrome`"

Comment: Well nope, I am self-taught adult to be honest. Trying to get into codeing by myself and I found this exerises which I am working on right now for and hour and cannot find a solution..

Comment: You don't understand that you need to have `czy_to_palindrome = True` within the function. As a beginner you face the very common beginner problem with global/local scope of a name/identifier/variable where a line with assignment to a variable changes its scope within a function and lead to an error message.

Comment: Just write inside the function: `global czy_to_palindrome`, just in the first line after the function definition. And, read about scope variables. Sorry if I was not polite, I think that you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Happy coding!

Comment: Interesting thing is, that earlier I have added "global" inside but it didn't work but I could make some changes inside the code in the meanwhile. Now adding below works fine, thanks :     
"""
def palindrome_check(number):
        global czy_to_palindrome
"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they say in the comments, just add a global variable or pass the variable to the function. Here are the two options:

```
  while True:
        print("Podaj liczbe: ", end="")
        number = input()
        czy_to_palindrome = True
        def palindrome_check(number, czy_to_palindrome):
            for i in range(len(number)):
                if number[i] != number[len(number)- i - 1]:
                    print("No, ", number, "is NOT a palindrome.")
                    czy_to_palindrome = False
                    break
            if czy_to_palindrome:
               print("Yes, ",number, "is a palindrome.")
    
        palindrome_check(number, czy_to_palindrome)
```

Or

```
while True:
    print("Podaj liczbe: ", end="")
    number = input()
    czy_to_palindrome = True
    def palindrome_check(number):
        global czy_to_palindrome
        for i in range(len(number)):
            if number[i] != number[len(number)- i - 1]:
                print("No, ", number, "is NOT a palindrome.")
                czy_to_palindrome = False
                break
        if czy_to_palindrome:
           print("Yes, ",number, "is a palindrome.")

    palindrome_check(number)
```

The choice depends on what you want to achieve, if the variable is really a variable that you need to change in the rest of the program and stay that way, use 'global' otherwise use parameter passing.